# Place MKPlacemarks from JSON list..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, json

I have an MKMapView which I want to draw lots of pins that display annotation when tapped on. By receiving a list of pin latitudes and longitudes from a MySQL database, using JSON, I can now NSLog the JSON listed below. But please could some help me now get these onto the map?

Thank you!

I would like to use the 'name' and 'user' as the title and subtitle for the annotations:

```
[[
  [{
    "pid":"0",
    "name":"First pin ever!",
    "user":"Marshall",
    "lat":"52.279721",
    "lon":"-1.162913"
    }],

  [{
    "pid":"1",
    "name":"Second pin yay!",
    "user":"Admin",
    "lat":"50.279721",
    "lon":"-1.182913"
    }],

  [{
    "pid":"2",
    "name":"Pinny",
    "user":"Test2",
    "lat":"50.279620",
    "lon":"-1.182100"
    }],

  [{
    "pid":"3",
    "name":"Pin",
    "user":"Admin",
    "lat":"50.279730",
    "lon":"-1.182920"
    }]
]]
```

Comment: Is your problem parsing the json?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely look at `MPMapViewDelegate`'s `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation`. I *highly* recommend creating some model object to represent these locations, and have that object conform to `MKAnnotation` and implementing `title` and `subtitle`.

For example: init such an object so that the `coordinate` uses the lat/lon from your JSON, `title` uses the name attribute, and `subtitle` uses the user attribute.